# Estrutura padrão de uma procedure SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho um modelo de estrutura, gostaria de saber se ela está adequada a um bom padrão.

```
USE [teste]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sprEstruturaPadrao] 
   --declaração de variáveis
   @idusuario int

AS
BEGIN
   --abre a transação para update e insert
   --BEGIN TRAN sprEstruturaPadrao;

   if(@idusuario > 0)
   begin
       --select
       select * from TB_USUARIO where idusuario = @idusuario

      if(@@ERROR <> 0)
         PRINT N'Error = ' + CAST(@@ERROR AS NVARCHAR(20));
         -- finaliza transação para update e insert
         --  ROLLBACK TRAN sprEstruturaPadrao 
      else
           PRINT 'tudo certo';
         -- finaliza transação para update e insert
         --  COMMIT TRAN  sprEstruturaPadrao


   end


END
```

Comment: Vai dar erro toda vez que executar numa primeira vez quando ainda não existir tal `procedure`. Poderia iniciar com um `if  isnull(object_id  ...  drop` e ao invés de ser `alter` seria sempre um `create`.

Comment: este modelo já tinha sido criado, ele estava sendo alterado apenas

Answer (score 1):

Algumas sugestões:

**(1)** utilize o comando

```
set NOCOUNT on
```

logo no início do procedimento, antes de qualquer outro comando.

**(2)** retornar informação sobre se o procedimento executou com ou sem erros através de `RETURN valor`. Se houve erro, a sugestão é que o valor retornado seja negativo. Por exemplo, se ocorreu erro 488 na instrução SQL, o valor retornado é -488.

**(3)** não utilizar `SELECT *`

**(4)** efetuar tratamento de erro utilizando `TRY..CATCH`

**(5)** Padronize como as instruções o T-SQL serão grafadas. No exemplo que postou, o "select" está em minúsculas mas o "PRINT" está em maiúsculas, o que demonstra necessidade de padronização.

---

Sugestão de leitura: [My stored procedure "best practices" checklist](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/835129/Stored-Procedures-Best-Practices), de Aaron Bertrand.